# remove different elements of a list in python

Tags: python, list, filter

I have a list like this:

```
["Dog owner writes for dying cat", **datetime.datetime(2014,4,3,16,21,57), ''**, "Get him a ball", **datetime.datetime(2015,11,20,19,18,23), ''**]
```

There are many elements like `datetime.datetime(2015,11,20,16,21,57)` and `''` in this list. How can I remove them?

**Remark 1:** the '' after datetime.datetime(2015,4,3,16,21,57) is a pair of single quotes.

**Remark 2:** apparently, the digits after datetime is the time with format year,month,day,hour,minute,second.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem have you run into when trying the solutions for removing elements from lists you have researched?

Comment: `newlist = mylist[::2]` if you always have that pattern of string, datetime

Comment: @StevenSummers: no there are empty strings after the `datetime` which should be removed as well.

Comment: Oh thanks, failed to see them, then `newlist = mylist[::3]` if it's always that pattern.

Answer (score 3):

It makes more sense to make a new list with the items missing than it does to remove them from the list.

**As a for-loop**

```
cleaned = []
for i in my_list:
    if type(i) is str and i != ""
        cleaned.append(i)
```

**As a list comprehension**

```
cleaned = [ i for i in in my_list if type(i) is str and i != "" ]
```

Comment: in your case you can do `and i` since you're explicitly testing for a `str` type :)

Comment: True. I think this is more explicit, however, thus better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply filter out `datetime` objects and empty strings with list comprehension:

```
[x for x in lis if '' != x and type(x) is not datetime.datetime]
```

where `lis` is the original list. This will **only** remove `datetime.datetime` objects and empty strings. So in case the list contains lists, integers, etc.; those are not filtered out.

This generates:

```
>>> [x for x in lis if '' != x and type(x) is not datetime.datetime]
['Dog owner writes for dying cat', 'Get him a ball']
```

Comment: `if '' != x` => `if x`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: but empty lists, etc. should not be removed per se. At least that is not specified.

Comment: That's not the same @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: I know that's not the same.